# I received a notification from Gmail that someone tried to sign in to my account. Is it legitimate?

Tags: gmail, security, account-management, phishing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Gmail sends “suspicious sign-in prevented ” emails or is it a trick?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26600/does-gmail-sends-suspicious-sign-in-prevented-emails-or-is-it-a-trick)

I've just received the following notification, apparently from GMail:

> Unusual sign-in location
>
> Someone signed in from a location that isn't typical for your account. If it wasn't you, change your password immediately. Learn more
>   1. Review unusual sign-ins.
>
> Norway
>   Prevented application sign-in
>   unknown.com | 148.122.197.152
>   Aug 13, 2012 8:30:10 PM
>   Suspicious
>   Undo

Is it legitimate?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that it is legit or not, but I suggest you to check that activity by yourself. **If that is true, you should change your password immediately.**

You can do the following steps to check the activities to your account.

1. scroll down till the end of your inbox in your Gmail account and click on *Details* link.

   [image: details]
2. Then you will find the latest activities to your Gmail account. You can check the country, IP address , and client that use your Gmail account. If you find unusual activities, you can click on *Sign out all other sessions* to completely sign out from all other sessions.

   [image: session info]
3. You can also double check the IP address that you have mentioned in the sessions information too. If that so, I suggest you to change your password immediately.